# Adding Accuracy and Loss Layer to RNN in CAFFE with DIGITS

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have just installed digits with caffe on the backend. I am trying to train [RNN with 50 layers](https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/blob/master/prototxt/ResNet-50-deploy.prototxt) on my dataset. To keep things simple, I initially have just three classes in my dataset namely `roads`, `parks` and `ponds`. By default, the above network dones not include accuracy and loss layers so it does not show any accuracy or loss on DIGITS interface during or after the training. To work that around, I just copied the relevant layers from `AlexNet` and put them at the end of RNN to see what's actually going on.  I added following three layers from RNN

```
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc1000"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    stage: "val"
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc1000"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  exclude {
    stage: "deploy"
  }
}
layer {
  name: "softmax"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc1000"
  top: "softmax"
  include {
    stage: "deploy"
  }
}
```

When the network is trained, it shows just 34% accuracy in DIGITS interface. When, I use `Classify Many` feature of DIGITS and classify the validation dataset, it tells me that everything is a `road` class hence achieving 33% accuracy in the confusion matrix. Since, I am very new to this field and I doubt that something wrong is done after adding the above three layers at the end of the network. Is that right? Have I messed up the whole network? What will have to do to visualize accuracy and loss in digits without screwing the network?
**Edit 1**
Below is the error that I get when I add the [facebook Resnet model](https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch/blob/master/models/resnet.lua) in DIGITS with Torch. [image].
Please note that earlier there was another error complaining about `cudnn` being `nil` which went away when I changed `require cunn` to `require cudnn` in network definition because it seemed a typo to me.

Comment: You don't need `softmax` after adding `softmaxwithloss`. Also this is a deploy module. Are you initializing weights from pretrained model? If not then you will need to add weight initialization parameters.

Comment: No, I am not initializing from pretrained models. How can I add weights as init param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't broke the network. You just don't need two `softmax` layers. Problem probably is it is not converging. As for network initialization parameter I couldn't find Author's `training.prototxt`. He suggested seeing [facebook's torch implementation](https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch) in [this PR](https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/issues/6) which has some changes than the original implementation. One thing you can do is use training network from [deepdetect](https://github.com/beniz/deepdetect/tree/master/templates/caffe/resnet_50) . But that PR's one of the conclusion was that it didn't converge due to caffe's implementation problem with `BatchNorm` layer. `deepdetect`'s author seems to disagree that it doesn't converge. Either way that seems to be fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5136) . So the summary is :

1. use the latest version of `caffe`
2. use `deepdetect`'s net and solver.
3. First check if it converge's on `imagenet` or `cifar` (loss reduces and error decreases)
4. If it does then train on you own data
5. If not then we will need more information about your setting

Comment: Thanks @inman for valuable guidance. I have sort of moved away from caffe and trained `AlexNet` network on my dataset that resulted in 86% accuracy. Same network trained of caffe gave me just 30%. Now, I am trying to use the fb Resnet that [you suggested in answer](https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch/blob/master/models/resnet.lua). When I load this model in DIGITS interface and click on visualize network, it gives me VisualizationError. How can I resolve this problem? I am attaching the screenshot of error in my question.

Comment: I am also looking for a pre-trained image segmentation model, that I can fine tune for my dataset. I would prefer a network for `Torch` because Caffe is not going well as far as the training accuracy and loss is concerned. I am thinking about asking a new question about it and I will post a link to it here in comments.

Comment: `torch` has both `cunn` and `cudnn` module. `cunn` is `torch`'s CUDA implementation of `nn` library while `cudnn` is the binding to the official `cuDNN` code. You should install `cunn` then check if the error still happens.

Comment: As for `semantic segmentation` You can select one from [here](https://github.com/carpedm20/awesome-torch) . I can't recommend much as I haven't used `torch` at all. But for caffe I can recommend [FCN](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) .  For torch you should try a port of `fcn`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I will give it a try and keep you posted.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but I see `download_model_from_gist.sh` all over the github but nowhere could I see where to get the `gist_id` for a specific model. For, instance what would be the `gist_id` of https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org

Comment: In model-Zoo, I can see the `gist` URL for CaffeNet fine-tuned for Oxford flowers dataset but there is no `gist_url` listed for FCN?

Comment: Why don't you just download the repo directly?

Comment: I can download the repo If I have to. That way, I will have to make sure that things are at their proper place (model, dataset, pre-trained weights etc.) and work in coordination without trouble.